# Hotkey for switching between pan and add point in QGIS georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm working on a project that involves a lot of georeferencing using QGIS's georeferencer tool. My workflow is generally as follows: add a gcp, then pan across the image a bit until I find another one, and repeat dozens or hundreds of times. Is there a hotkey for switching between the "pan" tool and the "add point tool"? This would allow me to more quickly switch and would speed up my workflow overall.

Comment: You could use arrow keys to pan, alternatively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 'Add point' selected hold **spacebar** to toggle 'pan mode'.
Releasing **spacebar** will return to 'add point' mode.

Couple that with the mouse scroll wheel for zooming in/out for a faster workflow.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it's not working for me--is this a setting I need to enable or possibly a version issue? I'm on QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires running on Mac OS Monterey 12.3.

Comment: Are you holding spacebar? Alternatively, try clicking and holding the centre mouse wheel. You could also try setting a keyboard shortcut for pan (Setting > keyboard Shortcuts...)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I was doing wrong before. Just tried again and it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

With 'Add point' selected, left-click to add a point, middle-click (click scroll wheel without scrolling it) and drag to pan. No hotkey required.